# How to add SSH Key in Travis CI?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, git-submodules, travis-ci, ssh-keys

In Travis Doc there is tab "SSH Key" in Settings, but not in my account. I need to add SSH Key to clone submodules on GitHub.

My Account:

[image]

Travis Doc:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature is only available for private repositories currently.

For public repositories, you shouldn't need them to be private Git URLs (assuming they're on GitHub), so changing the URLs to use public clone URLs should do the trick.

Comment: What if I need to clone a private repository in the build of a public repository?

Comment: @Xerus if in order to build a public repository you need files from a private one, maybe you're not really developing open source software.

Comment: It is only for the deployment. I am building an open-source-project, but each time we release a version, it is accompanied by a new version of a small closed-source package. It is much more convenient to build and release both with one CI build.

Comment: It sounds like you have the dependency backwards.  Make the closed source project deployment depend on the opensource project.

Answer (score 18):

Using SSH keys is only available for private repositories on travis-ci.com (paid plans).

With the `travis` command line tool you can generate a new SSH key which will be set up on both Travis CI and your GitHub user account (if you use a dedicated GitHub user for Travis CI).

Here are the necessary console commands:

```
# Install Travis command line tool
gem install travis

# Login to Travis Pro (private repositories) account
travis login --pro

# Generate and setup SSH key for your GitHub repository
travis sshkey --generate -r organization/repository
```

Instead of generating a new SSH key with `travis`, it's also possible to upload an existing SSH key with:

```
travis sshkey --upload "C:\my_keys\id_rsa" -r organization/repository
```

Once the SSH key has been created, it is recommended that this key will be refrenced from the `config` file in the `.ssh` directory of your Travis user. You can do this by adding these lines to your `.travis.yml`:

```
# http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-lifecycle/
before_script:  
  - echo -e "Host github.com\n\tHostName github.com\n\tUser git\n\tIdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

For more information, here is a link to the official documentation: [Generating a new key](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/#Generating-a-new-key).

Comment: docs for private repo and ssh key: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies

Comment: @Benny I did what you suggested! There were no issues with it.  However, when Travis CI goes to try to access my private repo, it still just sits there and waits for the username for my GitHub account.  How do I fix this?

Comment: @logankilpatrick Do you have a "git clone" command in your ".travis.yml" file or how do you try to access your private repo from Travis CI? If you try to clone it, then use a SSH url (git@github.com:ORG/PROJECT.git) instead of a HTTPS url (https://github.com/ORG/PROJECT.git).