# Travis CI is not updating git submodule

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

Travis CI is not updating the git submodule and it is throwing

ERROR: Permission to appdev/frontend.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I have already created ssh-keygen and added as Deploy key in github, but still its giving permission denied

```
Submodule 'frontend' (git@github.com:appdev/frontend.git) registered for path 'frontend'
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:appdev/frontend.git' into submodule path '/home/travis/build/appdev/b2b/frontend' failed
Failed to clone 'frontend'. Retry scheduled

The command "eval git submodule update --init --recursive " failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
```

I have added the ssh key in Github Deploy Key

```
.travis.yaml

language: python

git:
  submodules: true
  quiet: true
  depth: false
...
...
```

```
.gitmodules

[submodule "frontend"]
    path = frontend
    url = git@github.com:appdev/frontend.git
```

Comment: Deploy keys are [per reposittory](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#using-multiple-repositories-on-one-server). You have to have a deploy key for every submodule (please remember submodules are separate repositories) and configure SSH to use these keys.

Comment: @phd I have added deploy key for the submodule too, yet I am getting error

Comment: How do you configure `~/.ssh/config` so that SSH uses the correct key when cloning the corresponding modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a submodule needs to reference a specific deploy key (key1), you need to [change the submodule URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/6309), using [`git submodule set-url -- /path/to/submodule key1:appdev/frontend.git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-set-url--ltpathgtltnewurlgt)

With `key1` an `Host` entry in your `~/.ssh/config`, as commented:

```
Host key1
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1
```

[With Travis-CI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30872380/6309), that would be done in a `before_script` step.

Note that [Travis-CI recommends using User key instead](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/#deploy-key).